# Why would Azure Search Indexer stop working on a Live app

Tags: c#, azure, search

I have a .Net/C# app that calls the Azure Search Service.  It's been working fine to find a list of PDF files I have in Azure storage based on keywords submitted.  But a couple of days ago, the live app on Azure stopped working - no documents are returned from a search.  However, on Local, the app works fine with the same code.  I'm suspecting something may have changed with firewall rules, but I can't find where that may have occurred.  Hopefully someone has had something similar happen and has a solution.

Here's the code that stopped working on Live.

```
var indexClient = GetIndexClient();  // sets up SearchIndexClient with uri, credentials, etc.

SearchParameters sp =
new SearchParameters()
{
      Select = new[] { "metadata_storage_name" },
      SearchMode = SearchMode.Any
};
var docs = indexClient.Documents.Search(searchString, sp);  // this line no longer works on Live
```

Comment: Was there any error / exception?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it had to do with Microsoft's TLS 1.1 and 1.0 decommissioning in the last 2 weeks.  I was able to add the following to my code to make it work again (added to my page_load procedure in the default template):

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

However, I'm still working on an issue where the PDF links that are listed in an editor window (using CKEditor extension), will no longer work. I'm assuming this is the same problem, as it works on my local, but not from the Azure web app.